# how do I create list of list for N number which needs to be checked as factor

Tags: python

I want to have list of list for number say 20 as below output

list of the list of factors up to 20

[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,4],[1,5],[1,2,3,6].........[1,2,4,5,10,20]].

Unable to get function on it

Answer (score 0):

Use the [sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/install.html) library.

```
>>> from sympy import divisors
>>> [divisors(i) for i in range(1,21)]
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 5], [1, 2, 3, 6], [1, 7], [1, 2, 4, 8], [1, 3, 9], [1, 2, 5, 10], [1, 11], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12], [1, 13], [1, 2, 7, 14], [1, 3, 5, 15], [1, 2, 4, 8, 16], [1, 17], [1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 18], [1, 19], [1, 2, 4, 5, 10, 20]]
```

Comment: I got it by doing following code  

lst_of_lst_of_all_fact=[[y for y in range(1,i+1) if i %  y == 0 ] for i in range(1,choice+1)]
print(lst_of_lst_of_all_fact)